# Passing Multiple Filter Values in Post Request in Angular App

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, mongoose, eventemitter

I have a function that handles allowing users to check on and off various options within a series of filters in an Angular app. When one or more of these filter options is checked, I send a post request to the API to return data that matches those parameters.

Bottom line: I want to be able to query the API to return results based on the parameters of *all* currently selected filters, not just the most recently checked filter - which is what's currently happening.

Let me first describe what *IS* working.

Currently I have this working when a single filter is selected. Because each filter returns an array, I can select more than one option within that filter. So, for "zipcode" for instance, the user can select two zipcodes and the API will return results that match both of those zipcodes.

This works using a feature within Mongoose and our MongoDB, that allows me to send a post request with values matched to certain fields in the body of the request. The API call in my service file looks like this:

```
queryByFilters(page, pagesize, body) {
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    return this.http.post
    (`https://api.oururl.com/${this.ver}/clients/search?apikey=${this.key}&page=${page}&pagesize=${pagesize}`,
    body, options).map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .catch(this.filterErrorHandler);
}
    filterErrorHandler(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
```

And in the component, I am using it like this:

```
onFiltersChecked(value, type) {
    if (type === 'zipcode' && value) {
        this.filtersService.queryByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, {
            "addresses.zipCode" : { $in: value },
            })
            .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
                this.records = resRecordsData;
                console.log('zip: ' + value + ' type: ' + type);
            },
            responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
    } else if (type === 'lan' && value) {
        this.filtersService.queryByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, {
            "language" : { $in: value }
            })
            .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
                this.records = resRecordsData;
                console.log('language: ' + value + ', type: ' + type);
            },
            responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
     } else {
        this.filtersService.queryByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, {
        })
            .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
                this.records = resRecordsData;
            },
            responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
    }
}
```

The values are being passed into the component using Angular's Output() and EventEmitter(). I am also passing a "type" so as to be able to pass the correct value into the correct field. The component view looks like this:

```
        <grid-list [records]="records" 
            (sendZipcode)="onFiltersChecked($event, type = 'zip')"
            (sendLanguage)="onFiltersChecked($event, type = 'lan')">
        </grid-list>
```

Again, all of the above *IS* WORKING. Where I'm running into an issue is in having the request be able to process *more than one* filter at a time.

Right now, for instance, if a user checks a zipcode from the "zipcode" filter - it sends that request. If they then move to the "language" filter and select "Spanish", the request is sent out with the data filtered for "language" and specifically "Spanish" -- *but* the request no longer includes the filtered parameter for "zipcode", even though it's still checked. Hence, only one filter at a time is being sent, and it's whatever the most recently selected one is.

This is what I have tried to do in order to pass in all values simultaneously:

```
onFilterChecked(value, type) {
    if (value && type) {
        const lan = [];
        const zip = [];
            this.filtersService.queryByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, {
                "languages.primary" : { $in: lan },
                "addresses.zipCode" : { $in: zip }
                }).subscribe(resRecordsData => {
                    this.records = resRecordsData;
                    console.log('Type: ' + type + ', value: ' + value);
                },
                responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
    } else {
        this.filtersService.queryByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, {
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT: I am getting closer. After editing the "onFilterChecked" function to what I have immediately above here, I am now getting the correct values logged to the console. However, triggering the function makes the page go blank - i.e. I get no data returned. Again, I'm getting the correct data in the console, but not yet handling it correctly in terms of passing it in the body of the post request. How can I change the above function to address that?

Comment: What do you mean by _most recent_, _currently selected_ or _more than one filter at a time_ ? I don't get it. What is the _time_ problem ?

Comment: Maybe the if/else statement is not the better option in this case

Comment: Perhaps. And that's what I tried working around with my function that combined fields above. The only thing it's conditionally checking for now is if there is info coming in. But I'm not sure how to pass in the different values for the different fields when not using an if/else. Do you have a suggestion for how I could accomplish this?